# Elastic Search Multiple Publish Host

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, cluster-computing

Is it possible to set different IPs for Cluster Discovery and external connectivity

Like this:

[image: ES Cluster Setup]

I want cluster auto discovery to happen via the 172.16.1.1x IPs, and the external sources, like logstash, fluentd or couchbase will connect to the cluster using 192.168.1.10 IP.

Is this possible?  How to configure this

Note:
Currently I'm running the ES as docker containers, so in `network.publish_host` i'm using the host machine's IP (172.16.1.1x) and auto discovery is doing good.
I can connect to the cluster using any one of the 172.16.1.1x IPs, but I want to connect to the cluster using 192.168.1.10.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your `network.bind_host` to 192.168.1.10. This means that externally you can connect to your cluster only from this IP.

But a better approach is to have proxy like using nginx and give the 3 nodes as load balanced. You can deploy nginx at the server "192.168.1.10" and use your nodes as load balanced upstream servers.

```
upstream elasticsearch {
    server 172.16.1.10:9200 weight=1;
    server 172.16.1.11:9200 weight=1;
    server 172.16.1.12:9200 weight=1;
    keepalive 15;
}
```

Read more about using [nginx proxy here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/playing-http-tricks-nginx).

In this scenario you need to set your `network.bind_host` to 172.16.1.10, 172.16.1.11 and 172.16.1.12 respectively or alternatively set `network.host` to 172.16.1.10, 172.16.1.11 and 172.16.1.12. Using nginx will help you easily secure your cluster also.

The external tools like logstash can connect to the cluster using http://192.168.1.10:yourNginxPort

Comment: Thanks Prabin, the problem I'm facing is I'm running them inside docker, so `network.bind_host` should be dockers IP, if I give 172.16.1.1x, i'm getting cannot bind to IP. If I give `network.publish_host` as 192.168.1.10, my auto-discovery in failing to detect the cluster.

Comment: As I mentioned give `network.bind_host` as 192.168.1.10 and `network.publish_host` should remain as 172.16.1.1x

Comment: I get this error, when i set `network.bind_host` to 192.168.1.10 `FAILED SelectChannelConnector@192.168.1.10:10077: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address`. I'm trying your nginx solution. thanks much

Comment: The error is because the address 192.168.1.10 doesn't exist on the system.  The address has to be part of your system's network addresses. refer to http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html. Finally from the look of it you better use nginx proxy as you are trying.

Comment: Thats why I say, I cant bind to 192.168.1.10, its load balancer IP. I think your nginx solution will do, let me try that